# How to apply different rules to multiple appreances of the same variable?

Tags: replacement

For example, I have two lists. The first list `listA = {x, x^2, x^3}` has some elements involving the same variable `x`. The second list `listB = {x->1, x->2, x->3}` is a list of rules that says what value to substitute for each `x` in `listA`. After applying the rules, I want to get the result `listC = {1, 4, 27}`. What would be a short-cut to get `listC` from `listA` and `listB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MapThread[ReplaceAll] @ {listA, listB}
```

> {1, 4, 27}

Comment: Exactly what I was looing for, thank you.

Comment: Clear and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. Try this

```
listA = {x, x^2, x^3}; listB = {x->1, x->2, x->3};
listC = Map[#[[1]]/.#[[2]]&,Transpose[{listA,listB}]]
```

which instantly gives you

```
{1,4,27}
```

The `Transpose` matches up corresponding items. Just look at the result of `Transpose[{listA,listB}]` by itself to see what that did for you.

Then the `Map` uses the `->` on each pair of parts to combine them.

If all this `#` and `&` stuff is confusing then this is an alternate way of doing the same thing, just not written the way that more experienced people might do it.

```
f[{h_,t_}]:=h/.t;
listC = Map[f,Transpose[{listA,listB}]]
```

which instantly gives you the same result.

There are almost always multiple ways of doing anything in Mathematica, some of those you might never imagine doing. I try to think of the simplest most understandable way to show someone who might be new at this.